# revisiting $THH(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, arithmetic-geometry, hochschild-homology

Reading through Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze's ["Topological Hochschild Homology and Integral p-adic Hodge Theory"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03261) I encountered the following statement.

> We use only “formal” properties of THH throughout the paper, with the
>   one exception of Bökstedt’s computation of $THH(\mathbb{F}_p)$ ...

As a reminder, Bökstedt (and Breen?) computed $\pi_{*}THH(\mathbb{F}_p)$ as $\mathbb{F_p}[\sigma]$, where $\sigma$ is a polynomial generator in degree 2. Whereas ordinary (derived) Hochschild homology of $\mathbb{F_p}$ is easily seen to be a divided power algebra generated in the same degree, $\mathbb{F}_p\langle x\rangle.$ Note that in the latter algebra, writing $x^p = p! \frac{x^p}{p!}$ gives $x^p = 0,$ quite a different flavor than the topological theory.

At some point I looked this up and the computation appeared to rest on some not particularly formal spectral sequence manipulations which I was unable to follow. Is this still the situation? Has anyone revisited these computations recently?

Comment: This computation is essentially equivalent to the theorem of Hopkins-Mahowald that F_p is the free E_2 ring with p=0. That theorem, in turn, rests on the same nontrivial computational input as in Bokstedt’s computation: that the top E_2 operation takes each tau_i in the dual Steenrod algebra to the next, mod decomposables. As far as I know there is no proof of this presentation of F_p or the THH computation that avoids this fact.

Comment: Thanks, Dylan, I suspected as much. Could you help me understand what the proof would look like conditional on Hopkins-Mahowald? I'd happily accept it as an answer.

Comment: (someone upvote Dylan, I can't cause I'm new)

Comment: I’ll write it out when I’m near a computer, but the idea is that smashing the pushout square for S^0//p with F_p tells you the enveloping algebra is F_p smashed with a free E_2-algebra, and then it reduces to the fact that the Bar construction on the free E_2 gadget is a free E_1 gadget (eg classifying space of a double loop space on S^3 is a single loop space on S^3). There are references for everything too which I’ll give in the answer...

Comment: The computation also follows from the more general result (due to Blumberg-Cohen-Schlichtkrull) that if A is an E_3-Thom spectrum of a spherical bundle over a  (3-fold loop) space X, then THH(A) = A smash BX_+. In this case, you find that THH(HF_p) is HF_p smash Loops S^3_+. It's easy to compute the F_p-homology of Loops S^3; it's just a polynomial ring over F_p on a generator in degree 2, as expected.

Comment: @skd at odd primes, F_p is *not* an E_3-Thom spectrum over $\Omega^2S^3$. That is only true at the prime 2, so a slight modification of this argument is necessary.

Comment: I'd like to actually note that, to some extent, the hard input data is _reversible_. Given knowledge of $THH(\Bbb F_p)$, we can reverse-engineer the structure of the dual Steenrod algebra and the way that power operations act on it. This means that, if we could figure out an easier way to calculate $THH(\mb F_p)$, we would get with it a completely different path to some of the deeper computational aspects of homotopy theory. (So, to steal a joke from Paul Goerss, if you figure it out, you should call me. Collect....)

Comment: @TylerLawson this is exactly what I'd been wondering about. any chance you could show me how that story starts? maybe we could spin off a new question: Better Call Paul

Comment: To see the reverse argument, just note that $F_p$ at least receives a map from the free E_2-ring with p=0, whose THH(-;F_p) we computed. But a map of connective, p-local algebras which is an equivalence on THH(-,F_p) is an equivalence (this takes some explaining), so we recover the Hopkins-Mahowald result (from which you can, in turn, recover Steinberger's relation.) Another option is to note that the multiplicative extensions in the sseq from Tor_{A_*}(F_p, F_p) to THH(F_p) are resolved (by, e.g., Basterra-Mandell) by that Q_1 operation. For degree reasons, Q1 either kills \tau_i mod

Comment: decomposables, or else it brings it to the next tau_{i+1}, up to a unit. If it killed tau_i mod decomposables, you'd just get the divided power algebra.

Comment: @DylanWilson I think I had better go learn Steinberger's relation well enough to see what you mean. Where can I find it?

Comment: or wait, is it in "Homology Operations for $H_\infty$ and $H_n$ ring spectra?"

Comment: An alternative reverse argument is the following. Let $A = \Bbb F_p \otimes \Bbb F_p$, so $\Gamma = THH(\Bbb F_p) = \Bbb F_p \otimes_A \Bbb F_p$. Then there is an equivalence between $A$ and the totalization of a cosimplicial object $(\Bbb F_p \to \Gamma \to \Gamma \otimes \Gamma \to \dots)$ -- this is an Adams-Novikov / descent spectral sequence for $A \to \Bbb F_p$ -- and it turns out to collapse at $E_2$, recovering the dual Steenrod algebra.

Comment: @pupshaw Boekstedt's initial calculation, with some later simplifications, is explained on page 8 of https://folk.uio.no/rognes/papers/thh-fp-z.pdf .

Comment: @DylanWilson Sorry, could you please make precise the proposition that $\DeclareMathOperator\THH{THH}\THH(-;\mathbb F_p)$ is reflexive? Does $\THH(-;\mathbb F_p)$ means the $p$-completion, or equivalently, $\THH(-)/p$ is reflexive? and a hint of the proof is hopeful? and the word $p$-local means $\mathbb S/p$-local (also $H\mathbb F_p$-local by connectivity)? Thanks.

Comment: in case anyone stumbles on this question in the future, there is now a very pleasant lecture on these topics by Achim Krause https://youtu.be/BEt9zVdN0fY

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Alright, here is the promised answer. First, the Hopkins-Mahowald theorem states that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the free $\mathbb{E}_2$-ring with $p=0$, i.e. it is the homotopy pushout in $\mathbb{E}_2$-rings of $S^0 \leftarrow \mathrm{Free}_{\mathbb{E}_2}(x) \rightarrow S^0$ where we have $x \mapsto 0$ for the first arrow and $x \mapsto p$ for the second arrow. 
Equivalently (after $p$-localization), if we let $S^1 \to \mathrm{BGL}_1(S^0_{(p)})$ be adjoint to $1-p \in \pi_0(S^0)_{(p)}^{\times}$, extend to a double loop map $\Omega^2S^3 \to \mathrm{BGL}_1(S^0_{(p)})$ and take the Thom spectrum, we get $\mathrm{H}\mathbb{F}_p$. At the prime 2 there are many references, and the original proof was due to Mahowald- it appears, for example, in his papers "A new infinite family in $\pi_*S^0$" and in "Ring spectra which are Thom complexes". At odd primes this is due to Hopkins-Mahowald, but it's hard to trace down the "original" reference- it appears, for example, in Mahowald-Ravenel-Shick "The Thomified Eilenberg-Moore Spectral Sequence" as Lemma 3.3. In both cases the result is stated in the Thom spectrum language. And, again, let me reiterate: this is a **non-formal result** and essentially equivalent to Bokstedt's original computation. One always needs to know Steinberger's result (proved independently in Bokstedt's manuscript) that $Q_1\tau_i = \tau_{i+1}$ mod decomposables in $\mathcal{A}_*$, where $Q_1$ is the top $\mathbb{E}_2$-operation. (I suppose one could get away with slightly less: one needs to know that $\tau_0$ generates $\mathcal{A}_*$ with $\mathbb{E}_2$-Dyer-Lashof operations).

Anyway, given this result, let's see how to compute THH. In Blumberg-Cohen-Schlichtkrull (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0553.pdf) they explain how to compute THH of any $\mathbb{E}_1$-Thom spectrum, with increasingly nice answers as we add multiplicative structure. For an $\mathbb{E}_2$-Thom spectrum (i.e. one arising from a double loop map) we have that $\mathrm{THH}(X^{\xi}) \simeq X^{\xi} \wedge BX^{\eta B\xi}$ where $\eta B\xi$ is the composite $BX \to B(BGL_1(S^0)) \stackrel{\eta}{\to} BGL_1(S^0)$. So, in our case we have that $THH(\mathbb{F}_p) \simeq \mathbb{F}_p \wedge (\Omega S^3)^{\eta B\xi}$. Thom spectra are colimits, and smash products commute with those, so we can compute this smash product as the Thom spectrum of $BX \to B(BGL_1(S^0)) \to BGL_1(S^0) \to BGL_1(\mathbb{F}_p)$. But $\eta \mapsto 0$ in $\pi_*\mathrm{H}\mathbb{F}_p$ so this is the trivial bundle, and we deduce the result we're after:

$\mathrm{THH}(\mathbb{F}_p) \simeq \mathbb{F}_p \wedge \Omega S^3_+ \simeq \mathbb{F}_p[x_2]$.

---

It's worth giving the same argument again but in a more algebraic way, and, as a bonus, you can basically see why the Blumberg-Cohen-Schlichtkrull result holds.

The point (which is very well explained in a more general setting in Theorem 5.7 of Klang's paper here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03805.pdf) is that $\mathbb{F}_p$, as a module over $\mathbb{F}_p \wedge \mathbb{F}_p^{op}$, is obtained by extending scalars from $S^0$ as an $S^0[\Omega S^3_+]$-module.

Indeed, start with the pushout of $\mathbb{E}_2$-algebras $S^0 \leftarrow \mathrm{Free}_{\mathbb{E}_2}(x) \to S^0$ and smash with $\mathbb{F}_p$ to get a pushout of $\mathbb{E}_2$-$\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras. But now both maps in the pushout are the augmentation, and we see that the map $\mathbb{F}_p \wedge \mathbb{F}_p \simeq \mathbb{F}_p \wedge \mathbb{F}_p^{op} \to \mathbb{F}_p$ is equivalent to the map $\mathrm{Free}_{\mathbb{E}_2-\mathbb{F}_p}(\Sigma x) \to \mathbb{F}_p$ which is just the augmentation. This is tensored up from the map $\mathrm{Free}_{\mathbb{E}_2}(\Sigma x) \to S^0$, so we get that $\mathrm{THH}(\mathbb{F}_p) \simeq \mathbb{F}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p \wedge \mathbb{F}_p} \mathbb{F}_p \simeq S^0 \otimes_{\mathrm{Free}_{\mathbb{E}_2}(\Sigma x)} \mathbb{F}_p \simeq S^0 \otimes_{\mathrm{Free}_{\mathbb{E}_2}(\Sigma x)} S^0 \otimes_{S^0} \mathbb{F}_p$.

The left hand factor is given by $\mathrm{Free}_{\mathbb{E}_1}(\Sigma^2x)$, which you can see in various ways. For example, this bar construction is the suspension spectrum of the relative tensor product in spaces $* \otimes_{\Omega^2 S^3} *$, which is the classifying space construction and yields $B(\Omega^2S^3) \simeq \Omega S^3$.

---

Comment: wow, this rules! I've got to think some more about the algebraic argument but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: so what breaks down if we tried to run the algebraic argument in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: F_p is not the free E_2-HZ-algebra with p=0

Comment: @pupshaw  Also this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.7988.pdf  seems to give a nice explanation of the relationship Dylan is using between Thom spectra and universal properties of $E_n$ algebras.

Comment: The passage about equivalent facts in the beginning surprised me a lot (which is not surprising since I am a complete noob at this). The first construction is entirely inside the (?)-category of E$_2$-rings, while the second involves several violently non-ring things like e. g. BGL$_1(S^0_{(p)})$. Could you please give a reference to a more detailed explanation of this equivalence?

Comment: ...seems that the answer was just above my comment...

Comment: This argument is similar (identical?) to the one appearing in Rmk IV.4.5 of Nikolaus-Scholze. Is Nikolaus-Scholze the original source for this argument?

Comment: The argument certainly predates Nikolaus-Scholze... at the very least it's in Antolin-Camarena-Barthel (linked in an earlier comment), but I'm pretty sure the argument predates that too.

Answer (score 12):

This computation was given a totally different proof, not using any of the ideas being discussed above by Franjou, Lannes, Schwartz in Autour de la cohomologie de Mac Lane des corps finis. [On the Mac Lane cohomology of finite fields] Invent. Math. 115 (1994), no. 3, 513–538.  The relevant groups are Tor groups in an appropriate functor category, and [FLS] use some clever resolutions, a fun but easy to prove vanishing result, and ordinary homological diagram chasing/shifting to get their result.

All of this is much easier than the arguments by Breen and Bockstedt (or processed using Hopkins--Mahowald).  And their ideas opened the floodgates to other similar calculations -- especially after the Annals paper of Friedlander and Suslin that introduced the category of strict polynomial functors.

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers, I can’t wait to read this.

Comment: By the way, Larry Breen's paper is from 1978, a decade before all this other work, but no one seems to have paid any attention to it until the late 1980's.  Also relevant: he and Schwartz were colleagues at U Paris 13 (now both emeritus).  Breen's paper is Extensions du groupe additif. 
Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math. No. 48 (1978), 39–125.

Comment: I like this approach a lot and was completely unaware of it until your comment. But I’m a bit confused, the equivalence between MacLane homology and THH is referred to Pirashvili-Waldhausen, “MacLane homology and topological Hochschild homology.” But the latter paper seems far from self-contained, and in fact refers some of its computations to Bökstedt. Can one prove THH=HML without relying on these very computations?

Comment: Regardless of whether it can be a completely independent approach I certainly would rather compute HML than THH once I know I can. And this paper has much more of the flavor of the arithmetic applications. Really appreciate it.

Comment: The part of Pirashvili-Waldhausen paper that is of interest here - the proof that TTH(R) can be related to Tor groups in a functor category - is given a very conceptual proof; no calculations needed.  (They mention calculations only in a last section, which discusses how an Atiyah-Hirzebruch type spectral sequence behaves.  But this is really independent of the rest of the paper.)   By the way, Betley and Suslin independently gave nice proofs that these groups can be regarded as homology of GL_{infty}(Z/p) with coefficients in M_{infty}(Z/p).

Comment: Revisiting this in more detail, I seem to only be able to find a computation of the Hochschild cohomology as a ring in that paper. But this does not determine the ring structure on Hochschild *homology* (even, as far as I can tell, at p=2, where one does not need any functor homology etc. to get the additive answer). Presumably the stuff about identifying generators in terms of the Frobenius can be translated into some argument analogous to the power operations arguments, but it is not immediately obvious to me how to do that. Do you know a way or a reference?

Comment: How would you compare this approach to the homotopy-theoretic approach by Bökstedt et. al? Is this related to the recent approach in \[[Barwick–Glasman–Mathew–Nikolaus, K-theory and polynomial functors](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.00936)]?